# Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, lang, httpexception

Getting the following error while hitting the POST API call via postman for the following code.

Requirement : Place an order given the list of <component_id>, and . Consider that an order only implies reducing the current stock of each <component_id> by .

Spring Boot Application is Running fine just getting 400 Bad request in Postman and following in the console.

Error Log
2023-03-01T00:43:19.065+05:30  WARN 53443 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)]

Following are the details of my classes added:

```
**Controller Class**

@PostMapping("/shop/order")
public ResponseEntity<String> placeOrder(@RequestBody Map<String, Long> orderDetails) {
    try {
        partService.placeOrder(orderDetails);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Order placed successfully!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Failed to place order");
    }
}
```

**Repository class**

```
    public interface PartRepository extends CrudRepository < PartDetails, String > {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM PartDetails p WHERE p.carModelId = :carModelId")

    List < PartDetails > findByCarModelId(String carModelId);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM PartDetails p WHERE p.componentId = :componentId")

    List < PartDetails > findByComponentId(String componentId);

    **Service Class Logic**

    @Transactional
    public void placeOrder(Map < String, Long > orderDetails) {
        for (Map.Entry < String, Long > entry: orderDetails.entrySet()) {
            String componentId = entry.getKey();
            Long unitInStock = entry.getValue();
            List < PartDetails > partStockOptional = partRepository.findByComponentId(componentId);
            // PartDetails partStock = partStockOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Part stock not found with component ID: " + componentId));
            PartDetails partStock = (PartDetails) partStockOptional;
            Long currentUnits = partStock.getUnitInStock();
            if (currentUnits < unitInStock) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Insufficient units in stock for component ID: " + componentId);
            }
            partStock.setUnitInStock(currentUnits - unitInStock);
            partRepository.save(partStock);
        }
    }

    **Entity Class**

    package com.example.ecombackend.Entity;

    import jakarta.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    @Table
    public class PartDetails {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        @Column(name = "car_model_id")
        private String carModelId;
        @Column
        private String componentName;
        @Column
        private String componentId;
        @Column(name = "unit_in_stock")
        private Long unitInStock;

        public PartDetails() {}

        public PartDetails(String carModelIds, String componentNames, String componentIds, Long unitInStocks) {
            carModelId = carModelIds;
            componentName = componentNames;
            componentId = componentIds;
            unitInStock = unitInStocks;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getCarModelId() {
            return carModelId;
        }

        public String getComponentName() {
            return componentName;
        }

        public String getComponentId() {
            return componentId;
        }

        public Long getUnitInStock() {
            return unitInStock;
        }

        public void setCarModelId(String carModelId) {
            this.carModelId = carModelId;
        }

        public void setComponentName(String componentName) {
            this.componentName = componentName;
        }

        public void setComponentId(String componentId) {
            this.componentId = componentId;
        }

        public void setUnitInStock(Long unitInStock) {
            this.unitInStock = unitInStock;
        }

    }
```

`

Comment: Please post your request body. As per the exception you seem to be providing one or more objects as property values, instead of numbers

Comment: {
    "orderDetails": {
        "EA1": 5,
        "BA1": 3
    }
}

Comment: @FlorianCramer this is the sample response I am sending to a database which I have already created in local and have these values

Comment: You specify the request body to be of type `Map<String, Long>`, so Jackson tries to deserialize `{ "EA1": 5, "BA1": 3 }` as `Long` (with `"orderDetails"` being the first and only key in the map). If you just send `{ "EA1": 5, "BA1": 3 }` it will work and be deserialize as a map with two entries `"EA1" -> 5` and `"BA1" -> 3`

Comment: Hi @FlorianCramer that worked thank you but now I am not able to update in my database getting following error class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class com.example.ecombackend.Entity.PartDetails (java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.ecombackend.Entity.PartDetails is in unnamed module of loader 'app') Gettting this for the above backend code when hitting post api Can you give me some hints on this ? This is what i Found while debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your body in Postman needs to be
{ "EA1": 5, "BA1": 3 }
not
{ "orderDetails": { "EA1": 5, "BA1": 3 } }

Comment: Hi @JohnWilliams that worked thank you but now I am not able to update in my database getting following error 

class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class com.example.ecombackend.Entity.PartDetails (java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.ecombackend.Entity.PartDetails is in unnamed module of loader 'app') Gettting this for the above backend code when hitting post api

Can you give me some hints on this ? This is what i Found while debugging.

Comment: PartDetails partStock = (PartDetails) partStockOptional is a problem, try  PartDetails partStock = partStockOptional.get(0);